# Add a Menu on the Button in c#

Tags: c#, button, contextmenustrip

I want to create a button that when clicked, a menu will be shown. I want it to look like this (with an arrow on the side):

[image: contextMenuStrip output]

I tried the following code on the onClick event:

```
Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
Point ptLowerLeft = new Point(0, btnSender.Height);
ptLowerLeft = btnSender.PointToScreen(ptLowerLeft);
contextMenuStrip1.Show(ptLowerLeft);
```

but the output is this:

[image: code output]

How can I create a button with an arrow on the right and the menu will show right next to it when clicked?

Comment: I guess this is Windows Forms that you are talking about, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very hort answer is that I think you confused width with height. Just exchange the line

```
Point ptLowerLeft = new Point(0, btnSender.Height);
```

with

```
Point ptUpperRight = new Point(btnSender.Width, 0);
```

However, there is usually more to do. Especially, depending on the buttons position, the context menu may show up outside the visible area of the screen. I think the easiest solution would be to use a toolbar control. As far as I remember there is a control that supports this behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot Georg. :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Georg's answer: To add an Image you simply write:

```
button1.Image = Image.FromFile(yourImageFile); // or a resource etc..
button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use **menu** instead of **button** or you can add a background image with a small arrow which you can make visible on hover or on button click